# Jquery Dialog center aligned only first time after that it goes to top left

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog, jquery-widgets

When i open jquery dialog first time,it is center aligned,when i close it and open it again,it goes to top left corner.My requirement is that i should always be center aligned.

```
$("<div></div>")
.dialog({ modal: false,title:" @CultureAPI.GlobalizeString("ClaimsAuditAdmin","STATIC_POPUP_TITLE")"
})
.load("/ClaimsAuditAdmin/ClaimAuditAdmin/OpenCreateNewSetDialog");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("<div></div>")
.dialog({ 
    modal: false,
    title: "@CultureAPI.GlobalizeString("ClaimsAuditAdmin","STATIC_POPUP_TITLE")",
    my: "center",
    at: "center",
    of: window
})
.load("/ClaimsAuditAdmin/ClaimAuditAdmin/OpenCreateNewSetDialog");
```

Comment: The code center aligns the partial view inside the <div></div> tag,but this div opens at top left corner.

Comment: Ok, remove my:.. at:.., of:.. and add position:["center","center"]